# Super Vector Machine: multi-label or multi-class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

My dataset (MY_DATA) has comments extracted from a social network labeled with the relative Sentiment (in this way -> positive: 1, negative: -1, neutral: 0)

```
   Comment    Sentiment

    Hello!            0
I hate you           -1
  Good job            1
    etc...       etc...
```

I would like to build a model based on these data to classify comments as positive, negative and neutral. So I applied tf-idf and then an SVM.
My problem is the following; there are many types of SVM and in my case **I THINK** we are talking about **multi-label and not multi-class** classification, which method should I use? linear SVM, not-linear SVM or the OneVsRestClassifier method?

Comment: Actually the problem you are trying to solve is Multi-class and not Multi-label. Have a look here for more details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/what-is-the-difference-between-multiclass-and-multilabel-problem

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic]. You might be able to find a more relevant Stack Exchange site in [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524).

Answer (score 0):

I think vanilla SVM only for binary classification, so I would suggest using the OneVsRestClassifier method?.

As for linear or non-linear, you should train and test the performance and decide.